# How to get the bit size (bit length) of an integer?

Tags: binary, big-numbers

Suppose I have the integer 255, so 11111111 is its base 2 (bit) representation and the bit size of 255 is 8.

How can I calculate the bit size of a (big) integer in Mathematica?

Is there a built in command to do that?

For example, get the bit size of this number:

> 2927830792549090642223927128245994370407730707421263941027999016984863\
>   0912510984361076745426566160527575471588512101075236999502833556564464\
>   0143433068092260733442122287098839310773059055086206120153515198219258\
>   3398767872924593087999752701698335718220740690349861031458470734962692\
>   3038457908116713132220756431585261807276890622491179809166640240727423\
>   4638027206000615626040059518008119647495121187340010342599638426421633\
>   8576751240728022900245840147015717947277804819529535526416662889228374\
>   6706468629147699490658964244983147481584083398771392660755122805961564\
>   6232235189593608657475480776903398421238729200205836458726287800099705\
>   0358443968871300659117135416050092702254367736854056906749254852543144\
>   3694151267594169161940659804689537402197491168015348254792206440317735\
>   9044042848797425848100671512433900298757949690015974346822013731231910\
>   2955628829900538139966080075143814948778191364059028356066552952768294\
>   2164682347620954539325716876951175523562310072129163601000525231574137\
>   1600673653354351636549060209732731465253358622650325814782996304822146\
>   3881825359514299355098051031632982976355385119756255805491633418151251\
>   7936289335488021612731448264926863136612284118410866200550379357890757\
>   849558223140502795152578737799914590886592

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`BitLength`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BitLength.html) or [`IntegerLength`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerLength.html):

```
BitLength[number]
```

> 4091

```
IntegerLength[number, 2]
```

> 4091

Comment: Or `Log[2, number] // Ceiling`.

Comment: Also, `Log2[number] // Ceiling`